# [AWS]s3 bucket web hosting not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm googling since several hour without solution.

I'm trying to manage my bucket as web directory but it's not working fine.

Here is my bucket policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an index html file at top level of the bucket, and a directory.

I can access the index file like this :

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_index_file.html
```

But all the following request give an xml access access denied error

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_folder

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_folder/my_sub_folder
```

I haven't found a solution. Please let me konow if someone know how to achieve this, so that I can browse my bucket through firefox or another browser.

Thanks

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean when you say you want to "*browse my bucket through firefox or another browser*" ...?  Browse the files?  Or see the *index documents* automatically rendered?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the static website hosting with the necessary index.html & default pages - you need to enable S3 Static Website Hosting. Just making the files / S3 objects public wouldn't help the index.html routing.

Once you do that you would get URLs like - `http://examplebucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`

[image]

Checkout the following links

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html

Comment: Yes I enabled website hosting, the same way as in your picture. I even redirected requests errors using Redirection Rules. But It's not working as I explaned above.
Without enabling website hosting I could not be able to access the index page. The problem is with other folders in my bucket.
It seems like enabling website hosting is not sufficient.

Comment: could you check if any S3 bucket policy or S3 ACL blocking the list

Comment: @papiveron, please read the answer again, more carefully, and perhaps the documentation, as well...  First, please note that web site hosting operates with a different hostname, which you can find in the console.  Your examples in the question are using the **REST** endpoint, not the **Website** endpoint URL.  Additionally, the web site hosting feature, including index documents, does not support SSL.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create 2 buckets, one for example.com and one for www.example.com
2. Set bucket policy for both like below:

   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": "s3:GetObject",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
       }
   ]
   }
3. Follow this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html